# Are the Withhold Release Orders published by US Customs and Border Protection the subject of the CBP's own investigations; is such evidence published?

Tags: trade, employment, slavery

The US CBP has issued a Withhold Release Order on a major Malaysian palm oil producer

https://www.cbp.gov/newsroom/national-media-release/cbp-issues-detention-order-palm-oil-produced-forced-labor-malaysia

*CBP’s Office of Trade directed the issuance of a Withhold Release Order (WRO) against palm oil and palm oil products made by FGV based on information that reasonably indicates the use of forced labor. The order is the result of a year-long investigation that revealed forced labor indicators including abuse of vulnerability, deception, restriction of movement, isolation, physical and sexual violence, intimidation and threats, retention of identity documents, withholding of wages, debt bondage, abusive working and living conditions, and excessive overtime. The investigation also raised concerns that forced child labor is potentially being used in FGV’s palm oil production process.*

and

*CBP receives allegations of forced labor from a variety of sources, including from the general public. Any person or organization that has reason to believe merchandise produced with the use of forced labor is being, or likely to be, imported into the United States can report detailed allegations by contacting CBP through the e-Allegations Online Trade Violation Reporting System or by calling 1-800-BE-ALERT.*

I am interested to see the specific findings, and whether these were the result of the CBP's own investigation, or merely on receipt of a complaint.

I found such a petition, issued in 2019

https://www.gelaw.com/esg-institute/ESG_Institute_Palm_Oil_Petition.pdf
https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/grant--eisenhofer-esg-institute-petitions-us-government-to-block-importation-of-palm-oil-produced-by-fgv-holdings-berhad-in-malaysia-based-on-evidence-of-child-and-forced-labor-practices-300873707.html

The petition is essentially a compilation of links relating FGV.

FGV were suspended by the RSPO following a 2015 WSJ article and remain suspended

https://askrspo.force.com/Complaint/s/case/50090000028Es0aAAC/detail

In general the comments about foreign labourers paying commission to agents do not surprise me, living in the region, so I would not be surprised if other Malaysian palm oil producers are worse.

I note that P&G works with FGV https://us.pg.com/blogs/pg-to-invest-in-fgv/

So my personal feeling is that FGV have probably made improvements since, say, 2015, and may well be better than other suppliers as a result - perhaps they have been unfortunate in some ways to have been the subject of more investigation.

So I'm curious if anyone can give more detail specifically about the US investigation, i.e. how much they would spend investigating this, the actual detailed findings, and so on. Because there do seem to be accusations that perhaps have not appeared elsewhere.

I do take it that the investigation most likely followed the petition by 'Grant & Eisenhofer ESG Institute', but if anyone could comment on the political processes that led for this firm being the target and Grant & Eisenhover ESG's motivations (could be just that there is plenty of evidence already online, cf. having to research individual companies in Malaysia), as well as any possible political element to the US CBP's reply, that would be interesting also.